# Addition of two numbers from user input using FASM

Tags: assembly, addition, fasm

I have successfully got the user's input and placed into bl and bh, but when i attempt to add them together, the result is not in decimal form even if I already added '0' to the result. Any ideas on how to solve this problem? Thanks

```
org 100h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, msg
int 21h

mov ah, 1
int 21h

mov [number], al
mov bl, [number]

mov ah, 2
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, msg2
int 21h

mov ah, 1
int 21h

mov [number], al
mov bh, [number]

add bh, bl
add bh, 30h

mov ah, 2
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, sum
int 21h

mov ah, 2
mov dl,bh
int 21h

mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h

msg db 'Enter first number: ', 24h
msg2 db 'Enter second number: ',24h
sum db 'The sum is: ',24h
number db 0
```

Comment: If you're not very good at programming I suggest not using assembly. You don't seem to understand well the relation between number (digit) and its ASCII representation.

Comment: required by school. I have nothing to do about it

Comment: @user202729 : comments like your are what make Stackoverflow a poor place to get help. Did you consider he might be a student given an assignment? Learning assembly in one form or another, even for older processors is very common in academia in certain parts of the world.

Comment: @MichaelPetch ... then the OP's teacher must have taught carefully about that before giving the assignment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch <unrelated> What do you use those knowledge for?

Comment: @user202729 : I suggest you find another site where you can troll the users.

Comment: you're right michael. I am a student given an assignment. And as of now, I am not that good in assembly. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this one ?

Comment: Consider the issue. What happens if you add 9 and 9 together. The result is higher than 10. It is 18. You have to write code that converts a multidigit value to a string. I suspect that is what is causing your issue. If that is the issue, there are other answers on SO related to this.

Comment: @user202729: If you cannot help then stop commenting here, hope you understand.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: my assignment is to add single digits resulting to single digit answer only :) sorry i forgot to put that info

Comment: So you can't have a result higher than 9?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: yes mike, because later we are going to deal with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seems to misunderstood the relation between ASCII codes and values.

Assume the user input `34`. With your code, you set `bl` to the ASCII value of the character `3` (which is `0x33`) and `bh` to the ASCII value of the character `4` (`0x34`).

Now, to add them together, you need to convert them into values. By subtracting `0x30`.

```
sub bl, 30h
sub bh, 30h
```

Now `bl = 3, bh = 4`. just add them together.

```
add bh, bl
```

Now `bh = 7`. Convert it to ASCII value of the digit and display it to the user. That part you already did it correctly.

```
add bh, 30h
...
```

---

In summary:

- After read a digit, subtract it by `30h`.
- Before printing a digit, add `30h` to it.

Comment: Thank you! now its working. I'm sorry to disturb you

Comment: Because you subtract 2·0x30 and then add 0x30, you just could subtract 0x30 for some little optimisation. :)